# How to change a CGDisplayStreamRef property?

Tags: macos, screen-capture

I create a CGDisplayStreamRef use `CGDisplayStreamCreateWithDispatchQueue()`, this method have a param "propeties".

Now I want to change the property, but I didn't found any interface like "SetProperty", "UpdateOptions"...

Who can help me? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there's any way to do this. For example, the page documenting the [Display Stream Optional Property Keys](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/quartz_display_services/display_stream_optional_property_keys?language=objc) says, "These keys are used to populate the properties dictionary used when **creating a new display stream**." (Emphasis added.) And, as you've noted, there's no function for changing the properties of an existing stream.

And it makes sense. Those properties are intrinsic to the stream. Different properties would make for a different stream. So, you would have to actually create a separate stream. I guess you would stop one and start the other.

Comment: Yeah, I try to stop and start a new, it be successful, tyvm.